# How do VS Code langauge extensions distribute a language server binary?

Tags: distribution

I'm working on implementing a language server and corresponding Visual Studio Code extension for a small scripting language. The language server is implemented in Rust, so I can generate binaries that the VS Code extension can execute to support several editor features. I am trying to decide how to handle distributing the language server binary.

How do VS Code extensions typically handle distributing language server binaries? If there are multiple approaches used, what tradeoffs do they have?

### Thoughts on potential approaches

Here are some of my thoughts on potential implementation strategies. I'm not sure which, if any of these are actually used in practice.

#### Ship all binaries with extension

I could try to include all of the binaries for the language server for different OS's within the extension and have the extension just call on the one that supports the user's OS.

- Pros

  - Don't need to worry about the user needing any dependencies.
  - Don't need to worry about the server hosting the binaries (GitHub) going down.
- Cons

  - Need to ship multiple binaries with the extension, increasing the file size and download time of the extension.
  - Need to compile binaries for each possible OS that a user might be using (Windows, Mac, Linux).

#### Download pre-compiled binary on first run

I could have the extension download a pre-built release version of a language server binary that supports their OS.

- Pros

  - Don't need to ship any binaries with the extension.
  - Don't need to worry about the user needing any dependencies.
- Cons

  - Need to compile binaries for each possible OS that a user might be using (Windows, Mac, Linux).

#### Download and compile from source

I could have the extension download the source code and attempt to compile the binary for the language server using a build tool already on the user's system.

- Pros

  - Don't need to worry about the OS the binary supports, since the compiler will handle generating the correct kind of binary.
  - Don't need to ship any binaries with the extension.
- Cons

  - **Requires the user to have the needed build tool already installed**.
  - Takes time to compile the binary.
  - If the compilation fails, then the issue could be difficult for the user to troubleshoot.

Comment: The VSCode Rust extension downloads rust-analyzer on first run. Building binaries for all major platforms is easy, especially with Rust, especially with a CI system like GitHub actions. So downloading seems to be the least worse approach.

Comment: It looks like the VSCode Haskell extension also downloads the binary on the first run: https://github.com/haskell/vscode-haskell/blob/b14b3735d4582de485342cc8f5c51b2892caea5b/src/hlsBinaries.ts#L145-L162

Comment: I ended up implementing it by having the extension download the binary when it is first run.